# How can I pass collection of number pairs as parameter to IN clause with Dapper and Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, dapper

How can I parameterize this query with Dapper and Oracle database?

```
SELECT COLUMN_C FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B) IN ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```

In other words, I need to send collection of number pairs as `:parameters` to this query

```
SELECT COLUMN_C FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B) IN :parameters
```

Comment: you can't do that.  Need to be individual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass multiple SQL parameter values as a single bind variable. You would have to do something like this:

```
WHERE (COLUMN_A = 1 AND COLUMN_B = 2)
   OR (COLUMN_A = 3 AND COLUMN_B = 4)
   OR (COLUMN_A = 5 AND COLUMN_B = 6) ...
```

or, with bind variables:

```
WHERE (COLUMN_A = :VALUE1 AND COLUMN_B = :VALUE2)
   OR (COLUMN_A = :VALUE3 AND COLUMN_B = :VALUE4)
   OR (COLUMN_A = :VALUE5 AND COLUMN_B = :VALUE6) ...
```

and you would have to build the SQL statement dynamically if you didn't know exactly how many number pairs you were dealing with.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Isn't there any tool that could help me with this? I feel like I am the first one who is using Dapper with Oracle. Passing collection of number pairs, passing empty collection, passing collection with more than 1000 items, it seems that the answer is always "build your own SQL".

Comment: This is a limitation of SQL, not Dapper or Oracle. And since Dapper doesn't do any SQL for you the answer is always "build your own SQL".

Comment: @PalleDue Acording to https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ the query I used in my question is valid SQL, so I don't think this is limitation of SQL.

Comment: Oracle mostly adheres to SQL2003: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/intro002.htm